# Standard way to obtain a dict with both named args and kwargs

Tags: python, keyword-argument

In Python, is there a standard way to obtain a dict containing *all* arguments, passed to the function, both named and keyword star arguments?

```
def func(a, b, c=None, **kwargs):
    named_args = locals()
    named_args.pop('kwargs')
    all_args = dict(named_args, **kwargs)
```

UPD. Maybe this version is short enough not to search for "standard" alternative.

```
def func(a, b, c=None, **kwargs):
    all_args = locals()
    all_args.update(all_args.pop('kwargs', {}))
```

Comment: You mean something like `inspect.getargspec(func)`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but if you leave out the `c=None` kwarg in your function definition, you can then later obtain (with a default) as `c = kwargs.pop('c', None)`.

Comment: @Evert it was just an example, I could write `c=1` as well. By the way, usually `arg=None, **kwargs` makes sense, it self-documents the function.